# Which is the winning choice?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are $2$ players $A$ and $B$ who plays tennis. Probability that A wins any match is $P_A$ and is greater than the probability of B winning a match denoted by $P_B$.

Now, I am going to a play a $3$-match game against them and if I win $2$ consecutive matches I am considered the winner.

Thus, the $2$ winning cases ARE $WW\_$ and $LWW$.

I have $2$ options to pick from?

1. Play in the order: $ABA$
2. Play in the order $BAB$

Which option maximizes my winning probability?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, WW_ and LWW are the two winning cases. Let us calculate the expected chances for you to win the 3 match game. We denote

$P_A$ is the probability that player A wins any given game, and $(1-P_A)$ represents the probability that player A loses, which is then your chance of winning. Likewise $P_B$ and $(1-P_B)$.

We follow by adding up the WW_ and the LWW case.

$EV_{ABA}= W_AW_B{\_} + L_AW_BW_A =$

$[(1-P_A)(1-P_B) + (P_A)(1-P_B)(1-P_A)]$

$EV_{BAB}=W_BW_A{\_} + L_BW_AW_B =$

$[(1-P_B)(1-P_A) + (P_B)(1-P_A)(1-P_B)]$

---

This is already it, but let's tidy this up a bit. Let's define $\alpha=(1-P_A)(1-P_B)$ to get

$EV_{ABA}=\alpha + (\alpha\times P_A)$

$EV_{BAB}=\alpha + (\alpha\times P_B)$.

This now makes the solution apparent. As $P_A > P_B$, we have

$EV_{ABA} > EV_{BAB}$.

---

An intuitive way to understand this, is that you know a priori that you have to win the second game, otherwise you're out. Winning this second game is more likely against player B than player A, so ABA is your choice.

Another intuitive way is to not consider the WW_ case, since the chances of $W_A|W_B$ (win against A after a win against B) and $W_B|W_A$ are equal, and thus concentrate on the LWW case, which again features the above, but now dependent on the loss of the first match, which itself (the loss) is more likely to happen against player A than against player B.

Comment: $W_AW_{B-}$ should have probability $P_A^2$ no?

Comment: @Alborz Note that $A$ and $B$ are not playing against each other. *I am going to play against them* and $W_A$ is a win against $A$ and $W_B$ is a win against $B$.

Comment: @DanielMathias ah, woops. Thanks